# Divergent Philosophies, Convergent Mission

Tags: discussion

There's been plenty of talk about what we're doing *wrong* lately. Here's a little post about what I believe we're doing *right*. It's also an attempt to document what I believe are the three main overarching philosophies at work on this site. As always, feel free to respond if I've got it all *wrong* :P

### Divergent Philosophies

1. **Pluralism + Relativism:** This philosophical approach allows participants to bring their own perspectives *as is*, to include using the language they are most familiar with and making assertions of truth (since it is *assumed* that every post is merely reflective of the OP's opinion). I believe this was the initial predominant philosophy of this site.
2. **Pluralism + (pseudo-)Neutrality:** Regardless of whether or not one believes that [neutrality is a philosophical fallacy](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/775/pseudo-neutrality-its-enforcement), this approach allows participants to bring their own perspectives, but *requires* them to qualify assertions of absolute truth, either by assigning them to a source/position or by clearly stating that it is an opinion. I believe the site is currently moving in this direction, largely due to [commingling](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/777/423) the [existing site policy of 'showing your work'](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/536/423) with [this philosophical approach](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/777/423).
3. **A Rejection of Pluralism:** Participants with this philosophical approach generally view the site as a platform for their ideas and beliefs, which are usually expressed as absolute truths. Most of these folks get DV'd and chased off, but a few persist—largely because this approach to the site was tolerated when site moderation followed the philosophy of #1.

### Convergent Mission

Despite these differing philosophies, I believe the site has been moving in a favorable direction towards being more welcoming of "Jewish, Christian, atheist and other viewpoints as long as they take seriously the process of understanding the Biblical texts." Officially, we've stated that

> The answers [we rate](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is:answer) most highly [stem from and work up from the
>   text](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/533/43).

We still differ somewhat on *how* to handle content that doesn't show its work (*merely* DV, *require* editing, delete/close, etc.), but we all agree that [good answers will do so](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/777/423) and [we agree on what makes us unique from other sites](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/803/423). And those are *huge* steps forward.

When Jon asked, ["What kind of site do we ultimately want to have?"](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/735/423) almost three months ago, the question attracted eight answers<sup>1</sup> that each received a wide variety of votes from the community, many receiving numerous upvotes *and* downvotes (which showed the community's division on the issue). However, two users who *generally disagree* worked together to write [a post that was received more positively than any other answer to that question](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/777/423) (by upvote:downvote ratio). This shows the community's support of this position as well as cooperation from the two individuals who co-wrote the post.

Granted, there have been hiccups along the way, differences in applying the guideline, and a few bumps and bruises—this is to be expected because of our divergent philosophies (and differing sub-philosophies within these as well). But *overall,* we're moving forward. We're not spinning our tires as I felt we were three or so months ago. We're going somewhere. Not everyone may agree on the trajectory, but [judging by community votes, a majority do](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/777/423). How we get there is still a matter of disagreement to some extent, but overall we agree on the destination. **And that is a great thing.**

So be encouraged! We're seeing results and this site is becoming a better resource for those who have questions about the Biblical texts. Let's look ahead rather than behind, and focus on where we're going.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>There were actually nine posts, but [the ninth was deleted](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/738/423) as it was not really an answer, but rather another question.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Dan, I don't agree 100% with all you say here but I do agree 100% with the way you are saying it :)

Comment: +1 because I agree with your conclusions and like the attitude even if I disagree with some of your premises and trajectories ;)

Comment: Caleb and Jack, meta for the win! :)

Comment: @Дэн-A better answer than 'pseudo-neutrality', and one that accepts the site as a 'work in progress'.